# How to update value in one table from another table without any criteria?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE  dissemination_areas (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  area_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  coordinates VARCHAR(1024)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE  census_tract_areas (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  city_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  census_tracts_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  coordinates VARCHAR(1024),

  UNIQUE (city_code, census_tracts_code)
);
```

these tables are for completely different entites and both are filled, except that `coordinates` field is filled only in one table.

For testing purposes, I would like to update coordinates in second table from first one. I don't want to use only one `coordinates` walue, I want to iterate over first table.

How to do that in SQL?

Note, that no relation between tables exist. Also, `ids` are not conincide.

Order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cursor to get all coordinates values from the first table and iterate it, in each iteration you insert in the second table the coordinate from the current iteration in the cursor

Would help a lot if you tell us what DBMS you are using so we can help you with how to create such command

Comment: `DBMS` is in tags

Comment: ow i see it now, i don't know if cursors are supported in SQLite, i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
update census_tract_area
set coordinates = (select coordinates from dissemination_areas order by random() limit 1)
```

This will update `census_tract_area` with a random coordinate from `dissemination_areas`.

If you don't like the `random()` idea, and if there are at least as many rows in `dissemination_areas` as there are in `census_tract_area`, this should work:

```
with cte as
( select d.coordinates, d.row_number, c.id
  from (select d1.id, d1.coordinates, (select count(*) from dissemination_areas d2 where d1.id >= d2.id) as row_number
        from dissemination_areas d1) d
  join (select c1.id, c1.coordinates, (select count(*) from census_tract_areas c2 where c1.id >= c2.id) as row_number
        from census_tract_areas c1) c on d.row_number = c.row_number
)

update census_tract_areas
set coordinates = (select coordinates from cte where census_tract_areas.id = cte.id);
```

This basically assigns row numbers to each table so that they have a common field to use to join to each other, and then updates `census_tract_areas` with the coordinates from `dissemination_areas` where the row number matches.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same, but not random? For example, to merge in any sequential order?

Comment: So you want every coordinate in `dissemination_areas` to appear once in `census_tract_area` (but order isn't important)?  Do the two tables have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create new tables that map between the actual IDs and consecutive `rowid` values:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE d_ids AS SELECT id FROM dissemination_areas;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE c_ids AS SELECT id FROM census_tract_areas;
-- use ORDER BY if you care
```

Then you can update each row from the corresponding other row:

```
UPDATE census_tract_areas
SET coordinates = (SELECT coordinates
                   FROM dissemination_areas
                   WHERE id = (SELECT id
                               FROM d_ids
                               WHERE rowid = (SELECT rowid
                                              FROM c_ids
                                              WHERE id = census_tract_areas.id)));
```